# Is there a site synopsis page offering a little more detail than the one with bubbles?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-exchange

Given that the SE community is so fragmented (specific sites for specific topics or collections thereof), it can be a bit of a pain  to visit each of a number of specific sites' about/help page(s) to see if the question in mind is a good fit for that site. Is there one page (or collection thereof) on stackexchange.com that has a list of sites that is an aggregate of that information? (*Id est*, is there a page that has something similar to a site title as a toggleable drop down that gives the "about" and on-topic/off-topic information, rather than [one page with only links to and one-line descriptions of the sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)?)

If not, would it be feasible to create it or update the current page to provide a popup/modal via a "see more" link? Is that a "herding cats" type of endeavor to keep track of all the sites (changes to their help pages, etc) not possible to perform by some sort of aggregating algorithm/bot?

*Update:* I think my question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139125/is-there-an-easy-way-to-find-out-which-se-site-i-should-post-a-question-in?rq=1) in terms of the difficulty (inconvenience, really) and workable method to use in finding the right site for the question.

Comment: No such  thing, that's for sure.

Comment: So... what's the content for this box? Most sites don't really have much in the way of a site description. What you see on that page is used everywhere... in the "join site" box if you're not a user of that site... in the tour description box... the only page that's customizable (by mods) is the "on topic" page and those don't have a standard format that would make what is scraped there useful in a popup box like what you're talking about. Heck, a lot of them don't really have any guidance there at all.

Comment: @Catija I didn't realise that, but thank you for pointing it out. I assumed (from the sites/subdomains I've looked at) that SE has some kind of guideline/template for how to present that information in a standard way, for the exact reason of making it fairly easy to scrape/aggregate.

Comment: "Detailed synopsis" is an oxymoron.