Why can't I ask a question on Stachexchange's main site?
I'm new to Stackexchange. I assumed that I can ask general questions on the main site but this doesn't seem to be the case. I have to first choose a group or specific Stackoverflow site before I can do that? Or am I just not seeing the button? I looked on the entire site but can't find any. I'm only familiar with sites like Quora where you don't have to necessarily choose a specific group. Can anyone help me? I wanted to ask a question about when people first new the effects of lead and its protective properties on valves. Which means I need probably some very old mechanics that had their apprenticeship in the 50s or 60s. How should I proceed to get the best answer?

Each site within the SE network has its own scope. It is on the user to find the correct site and then take the [tour] and [help/on-topic] per site to see where a question could fit. Before posting make sure the question hasn't already be answered by using the on site search and then use the guidance in [ask] to make sure your question gets well received on the correct site. When in doubt you can ask a [tag:site-recommendation] question here on Meta. Read its tag wiki for what we need to be able to answer.

Slightly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139125/is-there-an-easy-way-to-find-out-which-se-site-i-should-post-a-question-in

https://stackexchange.com is not a question-and-answer site, so it doesn't include a Ask Question button.
https://stackexchange.com describes the Stack Exchange Network of question-and-answer sites.
Contrary to question-and-answer platforms like Quora, the Stack Exchange Network doesn't allow questions about any topic, only about the topics related to the scope of each Stack Exchange Network site. To ask a question, first, you should find if there is a site for the question that you would like to ask. For this, you might look at the list of sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Thanks a lot. I noticed that apparently I have to first choose an appropriate subsite right? Something that seems to fall in line with the question I have. Thanks anyway.
